# How can I get my asp.net MVC routing to use a default action within a sub-folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an ASP.Net MVC app where I need to place a certain section of code in a sub-folder named **web**.

I would like for the user to be able to simply type "http://www.mywebsite.com/web/mycontroller" and have it default to the action of index.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to set up my routing to default the action.  From what I can tell, it's trying to use the controller = **web**, action = **mycontroller**.

My route code looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "web", "web/{controller}/{action}",
        new { action = "Index" });
}
```

The request works fine as long as I include the /index on the end of my URL, but it doesn't seem to want to use the **action = "Index"** default if I exclude it.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "web",
        url: "web/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: @Scottie strange, I tried it on a test application before posting. I have tried again and it seems to work for me. Do you have any other route before that one?

Comment: Well, sort of.  I'm using WebAPI as well, so it's quite possible that the api2 routing is intercepting it.  I ended up using Areas, which seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: @Scottie I was writing to tell you an alternative was using areas. Good decision ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Areas, and this has fixed my problem.